# Why can't you invoke the fuction directly with the parameters with Func?

Tags: c#, func

I just have a question about the `Func` and `Action` delegate.

I just wonder why you can't do this directly:

```cs
public static int addTowNumber(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

Func<int, int, int> add = addTowNumber(1,2);
```

But you have to do this:

```cs
Func<int, int, int> add = addTowNumber;

var addNumber = add(1, 2);
Console.WriteLine(addNumber);
```

Comment: Because `addTowNumber` *is* a `Func<int, int, int>`, but doesn't *return* `Func<int, int, int>`.

Comment: Oke, thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By passing the arguments you are actually invoking the method, and returning an `int`.

To store a reference to a function, to be invoked later, you don't pass the arguments, which is why this is correct:

```
Func<int, int, int> add = addTowNumber;
```

You can then provide any arguments you like when invoking:

```
int result1 = add(1, 2);
int result2 = add(3, 4);
```

If you want to defer execution of a method with predefined arguments, which is what it appears you are trying to do, you need to create a closure like this:

```
Func<int> add = () => addTowNumber(1, 2);
int result = add();
```

Comment: Yes, thank you.Just wanted to know the underlying reason for it